# How to insert a faceless square of a person into an image?

Tags: javascript, json

The user forwards an image and receives a response through a json on that image, one of the answers is as follows:

```
"faceRectangle": {
  "top": 187,
  "left": 458,
  "width": 186,
  "height": 186
},
```

**The big question is:**

> Through the information shown above, how do I insert a square in each
>   top and left with the javascript?

**MY CODE [CSS]**

```
.teste {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
border: 5px solid #efff0d;
}
```

**MY CODE [HTML]**

```
<div class="col s12 m12 l6 xl6 center-align">
  <div class="container-image-uploaded">
    <div id="teste"></div>
    <img id="sourceImagem" class="responsive-img sourceImagem">
  </div>
</div>
```

**MY CODE [JAVASCRIPT]**

```
document.getElementById('teste').innerHTML.style.width +=  obj[o].faceRectangle.width + "px";
document.getElementById('teste').innerHTML.style.height += obj[o].faceRectangle.height + "px";
document.getElementById('teste').innerHTML.style.top += obj[o].faceRectangle.top + "px";
document.getElementById('teste').innerHTML.style.left += obj[o].faceRectangle.left + "px";
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the only problem in your code, but you shouldn't combine [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) with [`.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style). Most usages of `.innerHTML` are unnecessary, and that is true in this case too. `document.getElementById('teste').style.width` will allow you to get and set the element's width. `.innerHTML.style` won't work because `.innerHTML` returns a string instead of a DOM object, and then `.style` on it can't find anything.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Even though I remove the "innerHTML" it does not create the "DIV's" which would be the "rectangles" for each top and left, it's as if nothing happens itself.

Comment: I also see that you are using `+=` but you should be using `=`. `+=` means to add the given string to the value on the left, but `.style.width` should already be a number like 100, so adding `'186px'` to that would just get `'100186px'`. If you use `=` it will overwrite the value. Also, I'm not sure if `width`, `top`, etc. support suffixes such as `'px'` or only take numbers - try just setting those numbers without adding `+ "px"`.

Comment: am I just missing 'position:absolute' or 'relative'? That would be needed I expect.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use `appendChild` because then you can create your new dom elements in memory and add it with this method.

`.innerHtml` is also working but then you're more working with strings.

Please have a look at the demo below or this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/4a9h8wxe/).

Vue.js is not really needed in this example but with it's easier to work component based. If you don't know Vue then just have a look at the `add` method that's called by the mousedown eventhandler `markImage`.

As O'Kane mentioned in the comments, you need to be careful with your string concatenation. I'm using [back-tick syntax / template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) for the strings in my demo so you can easily insert your values into the string. e.g.

```
    var style = `
        left: ${pos.x}px; 
        top: ${pos.y}px;`
```

The same is also possible with single quotes but that's harder to write.  e.g.

```
var style = 'left: ' + pos.x + 'px; top: ' + pos.y + 'px;'
```

**Note:** [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) is required to work with template strings. With-out it browser support is limited [see here](http://caniuse.com/#search=template%20literals)

In the demo I've created two variants:

- SVG rectangles (less css required to make it work)
- DIVs like your code (requires more css)

I think both variants are working and OK. I would probably use SVG because it's easier to create and also exporting later is no problem. e.g. if you like to save it as a new image.

**A note to the css**

The following [zero-space width](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) character is needed to have the div react on the size specified. Probably setting `min-width` would also work.

```
.image-marker-png:after {
    content: '\200b';
}
```

```js
function getRandomColor() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

const svgOutput = {
 mounted () {
   this.svg = this.$el.querySelector('svg')
    
    let img = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image')
    img.setAttribute('x', 0)
    img.setAttribute('y', 0)
    img.setAttribute('width', '100%')
    img.setAttribute('height', '100%')
    img.setAttribute('href', 'https://unsplash.it/300')
    console.log(img)
    this.svg.appendChild(img)
    // setInterval(this.add, 50)
    
    this.image = this.svg.querySelector('image')
    this.image.addEventListener('mousedown', this.markImage)
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
   // clean listeners
   this.image.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.markImage)
  },
 template: `
  <div>
   <svg width="300px" height="300px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
    <button @click="add">add random</button>
    <button @click="add($event, {x: 20, y: 40}, {width: 50, height: 100})">
    add "x20,y40,w50,h100"
    </button>
   </div>
  `,
  methods: {
   add (evt, pos, dimension, color) {
     let rectangle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'rect')
      let containerSize = this.svg.getBoundingClientRect();
      dimension = dimension || {}
      pos = pos || {}
      
      let sizeX = dimension.width || 50;
      let sizeY = dimension.height || 50;
      let x =  pos.x || (Math.random()*(containerSize.width) - sizeX)
      let y =  pos.y || (Math.random()*(containerSize.height) - sizeY)
      
      // some limiting
      if (x > containerSize.width) {
       x = containerSize.width - sizeX + 1
      }
      if (x < 0) {
       x = 1
      }
      if (y > containerSize.height) {
       y = containerSize.height - sizeY + 1
      }
      if (y < 0) {
       y = 1
      }
      
      rectangle.setAttribute('class', 'image-marker')
      rectangle.setAttribute('width', sizeX)
      rectangle.setAttribute('height', sizeY)
      rectangle.setAttribute('x', x)
      rectangle.setAttribute('y', y)
      rectangle.setAttribute('fill', color || getRandomColor())
      rectangle.setAttribute('stroke', 'black')
     this.svg.appendChild(rectangle)
    },
    markImage (evt) {
     console.log('clicked svg', evt)
      this.add(evt, {x: evt.offsetX, y: evt.offsetY}, {width: 20, height: 20})
    }
  }
}

const imgOutput = {
  beforeDestroy() {
   // clean listeners
   this.container.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.markImage)
  },
  mounted() {
   this.container = this.$el
    this.container.addEventListener('mousedown', this.markImage)
  },
  template: `
   <div class="image-container">
     <img src="https://unsplash.it/300"/>
    </div>
  `,
  methods: {
   add (evt, pos, dimension, color) {
     let marker = document.createElement('div')
      marker.setAttribute('class', 'image-marker-png')
      marker.setAttribute('style', `
       left: ${pos.x}px; 
        top: ${pos.y}px; 
        width: ${dimension.width}px; 
        height: ${dimension.height}px; 
        background-color: ${color || getRandomColor()}`)
      console.log('add marker', marker)
     this.container.appendChild(marker)
    },
    markImage (evt) {
     console.log('clicked image', evt)
      this.add(evt, {x: evt.offsetX, y: evt.offsetY}, {width: 20, height: 20})
    }
  }
}

console.log(imgOutput)

new Vue({
 components: {
   svgOutput,
    imgOutput
  },
 el: '#app'
})
```

```css
.image-marker:hover {
   stroke-width: 1px;
   stroke: yellow;
}
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image-marker-png {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: +1;
}
.image-marker-png:hover{
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.image-marker-png:after {
  content: '\200b';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <svg-output></svg-output>
  <img-output></img-output>
</div>
```